# Why can't I see a friend's fair?

Tags: ios, snoopys-street-fair

In Snoopy's Street Fair, you have the option of adding Game Center or Facebook friends' fairs so that you can share things like trading cards with them.

I have a friend on Game Center who I know is playing Snoopy's Street Fair, however every time I try to add them using the "add friend's fairs" button (and selecting the "use Game Center" option), it always says "0 Friends added" and I can't visit their fair.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it? I don't want to be friendless forever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some searches, and it looks like this is a [known issue](http://getsatisfaction.com/beeline_games/topics/adding_friends_on_snoopys_street_fair) with the game.  The suggestion that the game developers have is "hard resetting" your handset.  This is like doing a clean reboot of the system.

I don't know what platform you're on exactly, but if it's an iPhone, the general directions for performing a hard reset are to press and hold the "Home" button (on the front of the phone) while you're also pressing the "Sleep/Wake" button (on the top of the phone).  After a few seconds, you'll see the Apple logo pop up.  You can let go of the buttons at this point.  It may take a minute or two for the phone to come completely back up again.

If that doesn't work, you'll just have to wait until the next update to the game.  This was scheduled to be fixed in the Christmas update, but it didn't make it in time.